# CMS + Java Application Server Integration Architecture

Tags: java, drupal, content-management-system, sitecore, tridion

Has anyone integrated a Java application server (e.g. JBoss) with one of the following CMSs (Content Management Systems)?

1. SDL Tridion
2. Sitecore
3. Drupal

I'm looking for one of the above CMSs to create/manange a corporate website which consists mostly of static content coming from the CMS, but also includes integration points into java web applications, which may also in turn use content from the CMS.  (There is a requirement to use one of the above CMSs.)

What CMS and Java web application server architecture have you successfully used in your engagements and corporate web sites to provide seemless integration of CMS site content with Java web applications?

Comment: It's obvious that Drupal has a strong community but does anyone have experience or suggestions for SDL Tridion or Sitecore?

Answer (score 4):

I've set up Tridion with JBoss, Tomcat, WebSphere, WebLogic, IIS, and probably a few more. Plenty of websites out there using Tridion & other technologies/applications (airline sites are always a good reference when it comes to integrating with other apps, and quite a few airlines use Tridion).

Any specific question on integration?

Ooops, just noticed this is a pretty old question, hope my answer is still of any use...

Answer (score 3):

We integrated Drupal E-Commerce with Navision, having Java in between to do the glue stuff.

Put simply, try to exchange data in XML. XML has good support in PHP and Java. If online processing is required use REST or SOAP. If not, things can be simplified by exchanging XML files via FTP.

If you want to provide node data from Drupal to Java (or any other system), generating RSS feeds can be done even without coding by help of the views module.

Answer (score 2):

SDL Tridion has full support for working with Java application servers. I've done several implementations personally, and I know of many more.

Answer (score 1):

Using [services](http://drupal.org/project/services) might do the trick for you. I know few friends who had integrated `Drupal with Flex` using services.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion, we'll look into the services suggestion.

Answer (score 1):

Have you looked at [Alfresco](http://www.alfresco.com/)? It runs on Tomcat.

Comment: It was on a list of cms's from forrester, but wasn't considered because it lacked some features that marketing was looking for.  I'm not sure which features those may have been unfortunately. Have you used alfresco? Can you describe it's strengths/weaknesses vs. others?

Comment: I only used alfresco a little, but it looked fine to me. I managed to integrate it with the rest of our system's authentication.

Answer (score 1):

Although it's not one of the CMS above: We use OpenCMS in conjunction with our shop application. In this setup the shop is the primary application built in struts2, EJB 3.0 etc.

Communcation between the shop and OpenCMS happens in two ways (although we currently almost only use first one):

1. JSON, i.e. read from an URL (a JSP) that returns JSON
2. Webservice

Both approaches should be doable with the CMS listed above, since they are programming language independent.

Edit: I forgot to mention that both applications run in a JBoss 4.2.3 instance, although you could put the CMS on any other capable server (like plain Tomcat in our case).

Comment: Thanks for the ideas.  We'll look into those options for the cms we choose.  How is the performance of the json interface under load?  Do you need to implement caching for heavy load? Can you give a description of the production infrastructure?

Comment: So far json performance is quite good, although we didn't conduct any thorough load tests yet. Caching is not needed but could be done in OpenCMS if necessary. The production infrastructure currently is just a single jboss running the shop as well as OpenCMS. Both applications have their databases on a single db-server.

Answer (score 1):

Although it's not one of the CMS above, we build a integrated Application of [Magnolia](http://www.magnolia-cms.com/), [Blossom](http://wiki.magnolia-cms.com/display/WIKI/Magnolia+Blossom) and Spring.

- Magnolia 4.4 is the CMS
- Blossom is a Magnolia Module that provides Spring Integration for Magnolia
- All our Stuff can now work with the best from both side (Spring IOC, and Magnolia Content Repository)

All together run in a Tomcat 6.

Answer (score 1):

I have worked with a few clients that use a Java framework (e.g. WebSphere / ecommerce) / SDL Tridion combination. This works well because the application framework looks after the application functionality, and Tridion looks after content and assets. Tridion's publishing model allows users to;

(a) Create and publish pages or components that incorporate selected functionality and content. CMS users have complete control over how the page works.
(b) Create fragments that can be published into the site that are included into specific areas of pages - allowing an existing application framework to to work with managed content.

I like the idead that Tridion is agnostic about the presentation server technology, and allows me to re-purpose content across all deployment platforms.

IMO Drupal & SiteCore are brilliant tools for building web sites, but it's seriously stretching them to integrate them with JBoss.

Answer (score 1):

I have published out static content from Tridion to a Tomcat application server in a couple of implementations in the past.  These have included a few integration points with 3rd party systems and were very straightforward to setup and configure.

It is worth noting that the latest version of Tridion also comes with a Content Delivery web service (also able to run in the Java application server), which (if you use Tridion's Dynamic Content Delivery) can allow external applications to access your content too.  This can be very useful for mobile applications, etc.

Answer (score 0):

[Drupal](https://www.drupal.org/) + iframe blocks (same approach with liferay iframe portlet)
you can implement some drupal module to manage your "portlet"
passing data from your CMS to the iframe may be a pain
but if you need the SSO only, cookie is enough..

Comment: Thanks @hope_is_grim - I'm not a fan of using iframes as they don't index well with search engines, this is for a public facing site.  thanks for the idea though.

Answer (score 0):

Have you considered using a different CMS?

Content.Node has a nice java portal integration and lets you edit the pages directly in the portal (if you have the permissions of course).

Just try it out: http://www.gentics.com/Portal.Node/content/demo/Demo.en.html

I built many corporate web sites and intranets using this combination (Content.Node + portal server).

Comment: We've considered many CMSs but have tried to limit the list to a few that have features that our marketing department has considered important.  We've also limited the list to vendors that provide support.

Answer (score -1):

I want to add to the last post, that Gentics Content.Node was extended to deliver Content to the following target systems using the open source content conntector project at https://code.google.com/p/gtxcontentconnector/.

Jboss Portal
Liferay Portal
IBM Websphere Portal
Sharepoint Portal
SAP Portal

The functions are:

Display dynamic navigation structures. Display content. Edit content directly from the portal. Include the content published to the poratal in the respective portal's search engine or add an apache lucene based search portlet.

Hope this helps!